# Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: Your host is not allowed to connect to this server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, windows-server-2019

My mail sending service is running on local. But it doesn't work on the server. **"Mailbox is unavailable. The server response was: Your host is not allowed to connect to this server."** I get an error. (windows server 2019)

Comment: That message seems pretty self-explanatory to me...

Comment: Can you post the relates code about the mail sending service? And whether the application is an Asp.net Core application or not? If it is an asp.net core application, can tell us your application version, then, we can according to it to create a sample and reproduce the problem.